# multi core processing in for loop using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multicore

I calculated vector using numpy.
How can I calculate vector using multicore and numpy?

```
import numpy as np

num_row, num_col = 6000, 13572

ss = np.ones((num_row, num_col), dtype=np.complex128)
ph = np.random.standard_normal(num_row)
fre = np.random.standard_normal(num_row)
tau = np.random.standard_normal(num_col)

for idx in range(num_row):
    ss[idx, :] *= np.exp(1j*(ph[idx] + fre[idx]*tau))
```

Comment: take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/ the multi calc comes out of the box...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to have a NumPy based solution -

```
ss = np.exp(1j*(ph[:,None] + fre[:,None]*tau))
```

Porting this over to [`numexpr`](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html) to leverage fast [`transcendental` operations alongwith multi-core capability](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) -

```
import numexpr as ne

def numexpr_soln(ph, fre):
    ph2D = ph[:,None]
    fre2D = fre[:,None]
    return ne.evaluate('exp(1j*(ph2D + fre2D*tau))')
```

Timings -

```
In [23]: num_row, num_col = 6000, 13572
    ...: ss = np.ones((num_row, num_col), dtype=np.complex128)
    ...: ph = np.random.standard_normal(num_row)
    ...: fre = np.random.standard_normal(num_row)
    ...: tau = np.random.standard_normal(num_col)

# Original soln
In [25]: %%timeit
    ...: for idx in range(num_row):
    ...:     ss[idx, :] *= np.exp(1j*(ph[idx] + fre[idx]*tau))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.46 s per loop

# Native NumPy broadcasting soln
In [26]: %timeit np.exp(1j*(ph[:,None] + fre[:,None]*tau))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.58 s per loop
```

For Numexpr solution with varying number of cores/threads -

```
# Numexpr solution with # of threads = 2
In [51]: ne.set_num_threads(nthreads=2)
Out[51]: 2

In [52]: %timeit numexpr_soln(ph, fre)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop

# Numexpr solution with # of threads = 4
In [45]: ne.set_num_threads(nthreads=4)
Out[45]: 4

In [46]: %timeit numexpr_soln(ph, fre)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.62 s per loop

# Numexpr solution with # of threads = 8
In [48]: ne.set_num_threads(nthreads=8)
Out[48]: 8

In [49]: %timeit numexpr_soln(ph, fre)
1 loop, best of 3: 898 ms per loop
```

Comment: I tried "ss *= np.exp(1j*(ph[:,None] + fre[:,None]*tau))".
But It is slower than my code.

Comment: Thank you Very much

Comment: Why not posting an answer about it?