# Most Pythonic way to multiply these two vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-einsum, tensordot

I have two ndarrays with shapes:

```
A = (32,512,640)

B = (4,512)
```

I need to multiply A and B such that I get a new ndarray:

```
C = (4,32,512,640)
```

Another way to think of it is that each row of vector B is multiplied along axis=-2 of A, which results in a new 1,32,512,640 cube. Each row of B can be looped over forming 1,32,512,640 cubes, which can then be used to build C up by using `np.concatenate` or `np.vstack`, such as:

```
# Sample inputs, where the dimensions aren't necessarily known
a = np.arange(32*512*465, dtype='f4').reshape((32,512,465))
b = np.ones((4,512), dtype='f4')

# Using a loop
d = []
for row in b:
    d.append(np.expand_dims(row[None,:,None]*a, axis=0))

# Or using list comprehension
d = [np.expand_dims(row[None,:,None]*a,axis=0) for row in b]

# Stacking the final list
result = np.vstack(d)
```

But I am wondering if it's possible to use something like `np.einsum` or `np.tensordot` to get this vectorized all in one line. I'm still learning how to use those two methods, so I'm not sure if it's appropriate here.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried already? Is it working? If not, in what way is it failing to perform as expected?

Comment: Added what I have tried already, though after the helpful answer posted below. It's performing as expected, but I suspected there may be a better or more efficient way to do this (either via performance or less lines of code).

Comment: @wolfblade87 btw, `A`, `B`, and `C` are not vectors; they are 3D, 2D, and 4D arrays resp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending the dimensions of `B` with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
C = A * B[:,None,:,None]
```

With [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), it would be -

```
C = np.einsum('ijk,lj->lijk',A,B)
```

There's no sum-reduction happening here, so `einsum` won't be any better than the `explicit-broadcasting` one. But since, we are looking for Pythonic solution, that could be used, once we get past its string notation.

Let's get some timings to finish things off -

```
In [15]: m,n,r,p = 32,512,640,4
    ...: A = np.random.rand(m,n,r)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(p,n)

In [16]: %timeit A * B[:,None,:,None]
10 loops, best of 3: 80.9 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lj->lijk',A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop

# Original soln
In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: d = []
    ...: for row in B:
    ...:     d.append(np.expand_dims(row[None,:,None]*A, axis=0))
    ...: 
    ...: result = np.vstack(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
```

**Leverage `multi-core`**

We could leverage [multi-core capability of `numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support), which is suited for `arithmetic operations` and `large data` and thus gain some performance boost here. Let's time with it -

```
In [42]: import numexpr as ne

In [43]: B4D = B[:,None,:,None] # this is virtually free

In [44]: %timeit ne.evaluate('A*B4D')
10 loops, best of 3: 64.6 ms per loop
```

In one-line as : `ne.evaluate('A*B4D',{'A':A,'B4D' :B[:,None,:,None]})`.

[`Related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901875/3293881) on how to control multi-core functionality.

Comment: To make the intention more clear, use `np.newaxis` instead of `None`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had no idea you could expand dimensions while broadcasting like that!