# np vectorize does not utilize cores

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

I am using python 3 with numpy, it seems that numpy operations are using all my cores well, but when I use a function with np.vectorize like so for instance:

```
f = lambda x: (x*1000) / 20 * 15 + 3
v_func = np.vectorize(f) 
v_func(arr)
```

It uses only one core for a long time (according to the cpu utilization chart).

How can I use it with numpy's multi core capabilities?

Comment: Neither lambda nor `vectorize` are actually vectorized in the numpy sense. `vectorize` is a confusingly-named convenience method that's basically a python `for` loop.

Comment: `arr = (arr * 1000) / 25 * 15 + 3` is vectorized. Treat the array as though it was a scalar.

Comment: For some reason many people stop reading the `np.vectorize` documentation half way through, and miss the disclaimer about performance. `The implementation is essentially a for loop.`

Comment: OK, so is there a way to implement something that is more effective using the existing numpy tools?

Comment: Look into `numexpr` module.

Comment: @Divakar would you like to post an answer with example and I will accept it?

Comment: Should be pretty straight-forward. Would encourage you to post your own answer on this.  [`Related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901875/3293881) on how to control multi-core functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using numexpr library using the following code:

```
import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np

data = list(range(1000))
arr = np.array(range(100000))
b = ne.evaluate("(arr * 1000) / 25 * 15 + 3")
print(b)
```

This library is creating a vectorized function that does utilize multithreading capabilities as explained [here](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr)