# Slowness of numpy.ceil and numpy.clip in ReLU thresholding: where is the bottleneck?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, performance-testing, ceil

This is a question based on (or follow-up of) another question: [Faster implementation of ReLU derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54969120/2956066).

In a spirit to come up with a *fastest* way of computing the derivative, I wrote some solutions of which one is:

```
In [35]: np.random.seed(0)       
In [36]: X = np.random.randn(3072,10000) 

# computing ReLU derivative
In [42]: np.ceil(np.clip(X, 0, 1))
```

While benchmarking this to [other solutions of Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54969428/2956066), I found out that the above approach is excruciatingly slow (north of **30x**). Below are the timings (from fastest to slowest)

```
In [43]: %timeit -n100 ne.evaluate('X>=0').view('i1')  
10.6 ms ± 203 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit -n100 (X>=0).view('i1')
13.6 ms ± 77.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [45]: %timeit -n100 ne.evaluate('(X>=0)+0') 
22.1 ms ± 16.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# the super slowest one
In [46]: %timeit -n100 np.ceil(np.clip(X, 0, 1)) 
317 ms ± 2.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

What is/are the factor(s) causing this slowness? Where does the bottleneck lie?

Comment: That ceil/clip thing is just way more complex than anything else you're testing it against, especially with what appears to be numexpr optimizing some of the options.

Comment: (Also branch prediction. The branch predictor has a bad time with that `clip`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're just performing a way more complex sequence of operations. For each input, your ceil/clip thing does the following:

- Is the input value less than 0? If so, set the intermediate value to 0.
- Otherwise, is it greater than 1? If so, set the intermediate value to 1.
- Otherwise, set the intermediate value to the input value.
- Compute the ceiling of the intermediate value and set the output to that.

(This happens in two phases, one where all the clipping is done, one where all the ceil-ing is done.)

You're timing this against options that do the following for each input:

- Perform a >= comparison between the input and 0 and set the output to that.

It's no surprise that the >= is faster.

---

Second, your ceil/clip thing is writing 16 times as many bytes as the >=. The >= produces a single byte of output per input element (the `view` is a view, so no data copy there), while your ceil/clip thing produces an intermediate array and an output array, both of dtype float64.

---

Third, the branch predictor has a bad time with that `clip` on a random array. It has no idea what branch will be taken each time. A more predictable array goes through `clip` much faster:

```
In [21]: %timeit X.clip(0, 1)
1 loop, best of 5: 211 ms per loop

In [22]: A = np.full_like(X, 0.5)

In [23]: %timeit A.clip(0, 1)
10 loops, best of 5: 86.6 ms per loop
```

---

Finally, at least on the machine and NumPy build I tested on, `numpy.ceil` is just surprisingly slow:

```
In [24]: %timeit np.ceil(X)
10 loops, best of 5: 166 ms per loop
```

I'm not sure whether it's hitting a software `ceil` implementation or what. This is probably going to be different on different builds.