# python 3 how to use multithreading with numpy linalg norm

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, linear-algebra

I am using python3 with [np.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to calculate the norms for rows in a matrix (norm(axis=1)), Is there a straightforward way, using only np to make it run using multithreading or multicoring?

Comment: I guess you can try to use numba - requested methods are supported by lib. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) that supports multi-core processing, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

def linalg_norm(a):
    sq_norm = ne.evaluate('sum(a**2,1)')
    return ne.evaluate('sqrt(sq_norm)')
```

To perform norm-reduction along any other axis, replace `1` with that axis number in the evaluate expression - `'sum(a**2,1)'`.

Sample run -

```
In [34]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.rand(4,5)

In [35]: np.linalg.norm(a,axis=1)
Out[35]: array([1.28545589, 1.57467272, 1.4460319 , 1.43656019])

In [36]: linalg_norm(a)
Out[36]: array([1.28545589, 1.57467272, 1.4460319 , 1.43656019])
```

[`Related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901875/3293881) on how to control multi-core functionality.

---

For completeness, few alternatives could be proposed.

An efficient solution would be with `np.einsum` -

```
In [39]: np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a, a))
Out[39]: array([1.28545589, 1.57467272, 1.4460319 , 1.43656019])
```

With `np.matmul/@ operator on Python 3.x` -

```
In [6]: np.sqrt(np.matmul(a[:,None],a[:,:,None])[:,0,0])
Out[6]: array([1.28545589, 1.57467272, 1.4460319 , 1.43656019])

In [7]: np.sqrt((a[:,None] @ a[:,:,None])[:,0,0])
Out[7]: array([1.28545589, 1.57467272, 1.4460319 , 1.43656019])
```

Comment: This is a solid idea, but I am aiming for something that is pure numpy, which is multithreaded in a lot of places.

Comment: @thebeancounter If you are looking for a numpy built-in, there isn't any AFAIK.